# login to website - in python 3 to webscrape

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, web-scraping

I am new to Python and seeking for help.

I am trying to webscrape this webpage that needs logging in:
https://censos.ccp.ucr.ac.cr/

Looking at the link HTML, this is what I found:

```
                <div class="fila">
                <label class="etiqueta7">C&oacute;digo Usuario: </label>
                <input class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) autenticar();"/>
            </div> 
            <div class="fila">
                <label class="etiqueta7">Contrase&ntilde;a: </label>
                <input class="validate[required] text-input" type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) autenticar();"/>
                <br /> 
            </div>
            <div class="botonEnviar">
                <input class="submit" type="button" onclick="autenticar();" value="Entrar"/><br />
            </div>
```

So according to the source, the name attributes of the username and password fields are codigo and contrasena... right?

I haven't been able to make it work. I'm trying something like:

```
import requests
payload = {
    'codigo': 'username',
    'contrasena': 'password'
    }
url = 'https://censos.ccp.ucr.ac.cr'
p = requests.post(url,data=payload)
print (p.text)
```

But it is not working.

Please help.

Comment: Try `requests.get('https://censos.ccp.ucr.ac.cr', auth=('username', 'password'))`

Comment: Whatever you are doing just do exactly that using this url `https://censos.ccp.ucr.ac.cr/index.php/usuarios_c/autenticar`. The rest should be as it is.